# How to get the current text of a given page id

Tags: mediawiki

I have a bot, that analyses the current text of some pages directly from database. The page ids are known. In the past the bot used `where revision.rev_id = page.page_latest && text.old_id = revision.rev_text_id`. After an Mediawiki update, the bot doesn't work anymore.

Nowadays member `revision.rev_text_id` is missed. The [docu](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Text_table#old_id) tells, that `text.old_id` is now referenced by [table content](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Manual:content_table#content_address). My problem is now, to to find a way from `page_id` to table `content`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After posting the question, I continued mý investigation, read the docu again and found the solution (table `slots`):

```
    SELECT p.page_title, t.old_id, t.old_text
    FROM   `page` p,
           `slots` s,
           `content` c,
           `text` t
    WHERE p.page_id                     = $page_id
     &&   s.slot_origin                 = p.page_latest
     &&   c.content_id                  = s.slot_content_id
     &&   substr(c.content_address,1,3) = "tt:"
     &&   t.old_id                      = substr(c.content_address,4)
```

But it is much slower than the old bot (tested on same server): 7 min instead of 1.55s for 11274 pages. Maybe I add some indexes.

### EDIT

After adding a key with `alter table slots add index (slot_origin)` the process needs 1.162s (a little bit faster than the old bot).